# iOS: JSON Parsing Separated by Comma

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, nsdictionary

Below is the code to get an NSDictionary from Google Places AutoComplete API:

```
(GooglePlacesAutocompletePlace *)placeFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)placeDictionary 
{
    GooglePlacesAutocompletePlace *place = [[self alloc] init];
    place.name = [placeDictionary objectForKey:@"description"];
    return place;
}
```

The code above stores the following in place.name:

```
"Name: Apple Store Palo Alto, University Avenue, Palo Alto, CA, United States"
```

The results appear separated by Comma.  What's the best way to remove the the name of the Country before storing it in place.name. I would like to only display the address up to the State.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rangeOfString:options:range with the option NSBackwardsSearch to find that last comma:

```
    NSString *s = @"Name: Apple Store Palo Alto, University Avenue, Palo Alto, CA, United States";
    NSRange lastCommaRange = [s rangeOfString:@"," options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, s.length)];
    NSString *noCountryString = [s substringToIndex:lastCommaRange.location];
    NSLog(@"%@",noCountryString);
```